# Problema de visibilidad de mi cuenta de Github

Tags: github

Buenas tardes a todos!

Hace poco sufrí el ataque de un virus ransomware, por el cual perdí muchos archivos de mi PC, y además me comenzaron a llegar alertas en un montón de mis cuentas sobre intentos de ingreso. Han podido entrar a mi perfil de Github, y si bien no me han borrado ningún repositorio, deben haber hecho algún cambio o algo, ya que nadie puede encontrar mi perfil, ni siquiera siguiendo la URL. Solo puedo verlo yo habiendo ingresado con mi usuario y contraseña.

No se si a alguién le ha pasado, pero escucho cualquier tipo de sugerencia.

Pd: en la configuración el perfil sigue indicado como "público".

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! hablaste con el soporte de ellos? me parece que te van a oder ayudar mas que nosotros

Comment: Si solo puedes verlo tu entrando con usuario y contraseña, el perfil pasó a ser privado, en la configuración del perfil, revisa el checkbox "Make profile private and hide activity". Por cierto te recomiendo que habilites 2FA lo antes que puedas, además de haber cambiado las credenciales que imagino ya hiciste.

Comment: Hola Patricio! Muchas gracias por tu comentario. Lamentablemente, no pude solucionarlo así ya que la casilla para hacer el perfil privado está desactivada. Por otro lado, si, ya tomé los recaudos de habilitar el 2FA. Un saludo y gracias nuevamente!